# Can I decorate a Django REST Framework ModelViewSet Methods?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django REST Framework ModelViewset offers the standard methods to update / create / retrieve objects. I would like to overwrite these method in the sense that they should keep their original behaviour as given by `ModelViewSet`, but just add to that a check in the beginning if the incoming request contains a certain query parameter. How can I do that?

Eg. I would like to have

```
class MyRessourceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = MyRessource.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyRessourceSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        # Check if "key" query param is in request
        if "key" in self.request.data:
            create(request)                        # <<-- HERE call the "default" create method.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the default behavior, you can do `super().create(request)`. Often when overriding a method, we add behavior before or after doing this.

Note that "decorate" has a technical meaning in Python and this isn't it. If you are interested in learning more, you can google something like "python decorator".